# update state multiple dropdown REACT

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, setstate

I have a button which adds a dropdown select based on the number of array item set in my state.

I am able to add a new dropdown, however i am having difficulties updating the state with their value for each dropdown. Every time i select the dropdown and change the option, the state reverts back to only have 1 item in the array.

any ideas of on how i am able to set the state with their current values for each dropdown that i have?

**[Codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/modern-wildflower-0oms5?file=/src/App.js)**

```
    state = {
            food: [
               {name: 'Apple', quantity: 1}
            ],
        };

    const addFood = this.state.food.map((item, idx) => {

    return 
         <Dropdown type="food"
              className="dropdown-food"
              label='food'
              key={idx}
              value={this.state.food[idx].name}
              change={(event) => this.setState({ food: [{ name: event.target.value, quantity: this.state.food[idx].quantity }] })}
         />

    })

    <Button styleName="add" label="Add Food" clicked={this.addAdditionalFood}/>
```

Comment: Your code seems to be incomplete, is it possible to edit and write the whole component ? jsfiddle or a codesandbox would be appreciated :)

Comment: my bad, i have added an example in the description. thanks

Comment: @yellowdev just a little check. At the beginning I've a dropdown and a button. Then I select a fruits. The effect is that now I've two fruits in the state. I click the button and than I've three dropdown.   ------ At the beginning I've a dropdown and a button. The I select  some fruit. The effect is that the state change, but I've a dropdown yet. If I click the buttons react render dropdowns for every single fruit selected.  What's the correct behaviour?

Comment: @SorcererApprentice - When I first load the page by default in the state and UI there should be 1 fruit (eg Apple)
If I click on the select and change the fruit to orange, there should still be 1 fruit in the state and UI but this time should be orange.

When click ‘add fruit’ there should now be 2 fruits in the state and UI. 1 being the old orange and the the other being the new default state of Apple.

Sorry if I’m not being clear. I’m new to developing

Comment: @yellowdev what about quantity?

Comment: @SorcererApprentice there suppose to be another field for quantity but I removed it for this example. I can figure that out that once their select part works.

Comment: @yellowdev okay. On monday I rewrite my answer so that your code will works.

Comment: @SorcererApprentice cheers mate. Thanks for you time and efforts

Answer (score 1):

I fixed your problem. Now the code works as expected:
1. When a click occurs on the button, a new dropdown and a new element in the
   state are added.
2. When the value on the dropdown changes, its state change accordingly.

To fix the problem I changed code only in App.js file. Here the full code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Dropdown from "./Dropdown";
import Button from "./Button";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    food: [{
        name: "Apple",
        quantity: 1
      }]
  };

  addAdditionalFood = () => {
    const newState = {...this.state, 
      food : [...this.state.food,{
       name: "Apple",
       quantity: 1
      } ]};
    this.setState(newState);
  };

  selectFood = (event, index) => {
    const newState = {...this.state, 
      food : [
          ...this.state.food.slice(0, index),
          {
            ...this.state.food[index],
            name: event.target.value,
          },
          ...this.state.food.slice(index + 1)
            ]};
    this.setState(newState);
  }


  render() {
    const addFood = this.state.food.map((item, idx) => {
      return (
        <Dropdown
          type="food"
          label="food"
          key={idx}
          value={this.state.food[idx].name}
          change={(event) => this.selectFood(event, idx)}
        />
      );
    });

    return (
      <div className="App">
        {addFood}
        <Button label="Add Food" clicked={this.addAdditionalFood} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Here the code to add an additional state for a new dropdown:

```
 addAdditionalFood = () => {
    const newState = {...this.state, 
      food : [...this.state.food,{
       name: "Apple",
       quantity: 1
      } ]};
    this.setState(newState);
  };
```

To ensure the immutability of the state, it is good practice not to make changes directly to the state, but manipulating the data of shallow copies. In this piece of code, I tell to do a shallow copy of the state, a shallow copy of food and, finally, to add to the food shallow copy a new value. At the end, I set the new state.

Here the code to change the state of  a dropdown:

```
selectFood = (event, index) => {
    const newState = {...this.state, 
      food : [
          ...this.state.food.slice(0, index),
          {
            ...this.state.food[index],
            name: event.target.value,
          },
          ...this.state.food.slice(index + 1)
            ]};
    this.setState(newState);
  }
```

This function takes as input the event and the index of the dropdown; the event contains the new value assumed by the dropdown - this value must be entered in the state. In this piece of code, I tell to do a shallow copy of the state, a rearranged shallow copy of food. The shallow copy is so composed: it's equal to original before and after the index position and different at the index position. The element at the index position is a shallow copy of the original, but it differs from the original by the name. At the end, I set the new state.

Here the code rendering the dropdown:

```
<Dropdown
          type="food"
          label="food"
          key={idx}
          value={this.state.food[idx].name}
          change={(event) => this.selectFood(event, idx)}
        />
```

Now it doesn't contain logic, but only a lambda. Don't define logic inside jsx, but use lambda at class level instead.

If change the quantity for the fruits, I suggest to wrap dropdown and input box together and pass to this new component two functions: selectFood and selectQuantity.

note: I apologize from my previous answers and them bugs. Now, the code works and apply correctly immutability.

Comment: thanks for your reply. i had already tried this before i raised the question and it does not work :(

Comment: @yellowdev when you click on an item of the select, what do you want to happens? .. with the code inside my answer, the behavoir is that a new select was added with a focus on the selected item of the existing one.

Comment: I want the state to update with the select values. I only want a new select if I click on the ‘add food’ button. With what you suggested a new select was being added when I select an option from the select. It was behaving weird and not what im after. There is a link to code sandbox in my description of what I have I currently have.

Comment: thanks alot mate. I got it working but your version seems much more better than mine. thanks :)